# How to detect if an element is visible using PHP?

Tags: php, forms

So I have a form where 2 out of 6 fields are visible to the user. The user can then click a button to reveal the other fields.

Each field uses the following PHP validation (Note: the preg_match is there to make sure they have entered a space as it's a *full* name field):

```
$multipleFormErrors = array();
if (!isset($firstGuestName) || empty($firstGuestName) || !preg_match("/ /",
    $firstGuestName)) {
  $multipleFormErrors["firstGuestName"] = "You have not entered your full name.";
}
if (!isset($secondGuestName) || empty($secondGuestName) || !preg_match("/ /",
    $secondGuestName)) {
  $multipleFormErrors["secondGuestName"] = "You have not entered guest #2's full
  name.";
}
if (!isset($thirdGuestName) || empty($thirdGuestName) || !preg_match("/ /",
    $thirdGuestName)) {
  $multipleFormErrors["thirdGuestName"] = "You have not entered guest #3's full name.";
}
```

And so on up until guest #6.

The results are then being echoed to the user using:

```
if (isset($_POST["multipleSubmit"])) {
  if ($multipleFormErrors) {
    echo "<div class=\"errors\">";
    echo "Please fix the following errors:";
    echo "<ul>";
    foreach ($multipleFormErrors as $error) {
      echo "<li>";
      echo $error;
      echo "</li>";
    }
    echo "</ul>";
    echo "</div>";
  }
}
```

The issue here is that *all* of the errors will display even if guests 3 - 6 aren't visible to the user. So If they submit the form with just the initial 2 guests filled out they will get an error because guests 3 - 6 have a value of an empty string. I think a way around this would be for PHP to detect whether the display value is set to block like you can do in JS so is this possible or do I need to do something different?

Cheers!

Comment: your PHP has no notion of "visible". The page as it lives in the user's browsers has nothing to do with what HTML your PHP generates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP happens on the server, Javascript happens on the client, and that's the crux of your issue. The server has no way (without a lot more coding and state tracking) to know if the client is looking at something or not.

I recommend:

- Keeping your general application structure the way it is (don't do that state tracking, which would require a lot more JS/jQuery/etc)
- Perhaps put your error code with the text box, so that the error only shows if the text box does
- Code your system with the full realization that guests (beyond the first?) are optional, so guest checking should only occur on server side if there is a partial name (As it is, the error shows if the guest is blank, which will often happen). A blank name for guests 2-6 is probably completely legitimate.